# logical swap shown as 2 separate partitions. Extended and Swap

Tags: swap, disk-management

i would like to ask why Ubuntu disk utility shows my 12gb logical swap partition, as if there were 2 different partitions? I just set 12gb for swap and made it logical. Was this a wrong decision? Why diskutility shows it as 2 separate 12gb parts??? Says one is sda1 extended and sda5 logical divided in 2 parts.Please help...

Comment: I believe that the swap partition is not an extended partition, just a swap. Not sure of the ramifications, may be none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is completely normal.

An extended partition is a partition that contains another partition-table and acts as the "physical" drive to store data on.

A logical partition is simply a partition which resides on an extended partition.

The above described behavior is because a partition table is only capable of using 4 partitions. And if you want to have 5 partitions you have to make a partition extended and have 2 more partitions on it as logical (resulting in 6 partitions).

They use only 12GB of physical space and not 24GB.